# Using d3.queue with D3 v5

Tags: javascript, d3.js, promise

I know that `d3.queue()` has been replaced with `Promise` in D3 version 5, indeed if I try to use the function I get:

> d3.queue is not a function

But I don't understanding why if I put this in the html header I don't get the above error anymore, but the code seems not working:

```
<head>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-queue.v3.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR**: You simply don't need `d3.queue` in D3 v5 because it uses the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) internally. Therefore, you can just use things like `Promise.all()` or chaining the `then()` methods.

---

As you probably know, [`d3.queue`](https://github.com/d3/d3-queue) was meant to be used with D3 v4, not D3 v5. Since there is no `queue` method in D3 v5, just trying `d3.queue` will, as expected, result in the `d3.queue is not a function` error. When you reference the mini-library, the error obviously goes away.

It's worth mentioning that `d3.queue` **will work** if used with D3 v5, that's not an issue:

```js
d3.queue()
  .defer(function foo(callback) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      callback(null, "finished");
    }, 100);
  })
  .await(function(error, message) {
    console.log(message);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-queue.v3.min.js"></script>
```

However, if for whatever reason you still want to use `d3.queue` with D3 v5 for **fetching files**, you have to pass the adequate function to `defer`, with the callback like this (here I'm using a simple JSON I created online, which is just `{foo: 42}`):

```js
d3.queue()
  .defer(function foo(url, callback) {
    d3.json(url).then(function(file) {
      callback(null, file)
    })
  }, "https://api.npoint.io/5b22a0474c99d3049d2e")
  .await(function(error, message) {
    console.log(message);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-queue.v3.min.js"></script>
```

The reason is that, unlike D3 v4 or lower, in D3 v5 methods like `d3.csv`, `d3.json`, `d3.tsv` etc do not have a callback as the second (last) argument. Instead of that, they return a promise (using the Fetch API).

That being said, the snippet above is not only ugly but completely unnecessary: just drop `d3.queue`.

Comment: Thank you, it worked! Now I would like to replace this code with promise. I have alread read your two answers about that, but I wasn't able to solve. If you want you could help me here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62952888/how-to-express-a-queue-of-promise-in-d3-v5)